# How to fetch internal key value and data in ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have tried the following lines of code in jquery

```
              <h5>Marks per Subjects</h5>
               <ul id="subjectsMarks">

               </ul>


           $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?action=fetchStudentIfResultFound',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                ...
                ...

            for(i=0; i<data[1].length; i++)
              {
               $("#subjectsMarks li").html(key[1][i] + ':' + data[1][i]+ "<br/>"+data[1]["Status"]);
              }
              });
```

In console data is like

0
:
Object
1
:
Array(4)
0
:
Array(1)
1
:
Array(2)
0
:
Object
Physics
:
"150.00/200"
Status
:
"Pass"
**proto**
:
Object
1
:
Object
Science
:
"400.00/600"
Status
:
"Pass"
**proto**
:
Object
...........

I want data in li should look like

Marks per Subjects

```
       Physics: 150.00/200
       Status : Pass

      Science: 400.00/600
      Status: Pass
```

Please help me !!!

Comment: in response how it looks?

Comment: 0 : Object 1 : Array(4) 0 : Array(1) 1 : Array(2) 0 : Object Physics : "150.00/200" Status : "Pass" proto : Object 1 : Object Science : "400.00/600" Status : "Pass" proto : Object ...........

Comment: print data using console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) for more clearification and show here @Nida

Comment: [{"_id":{"$id":"5715f58299fbad800100003a"},"student_id":36,"registration_temp_perm_no":"453654","roll_no":"31","admission_date":"04/12/2016","first_name":"Momin","middle_name":"Bashir","last_name":"Rather","dob":"7/9/1995","gender":"Male","blood_group":"","birth_place":"","nationality":"","language":"","religion":"Islam"...},[[{"Physics":"150.00/200","Status":"Pass"}],[{"Physics":"150.00/200","Status":"Pass"},{"Science":"400.00/600","Status":"Pass"}],{"Total Marks":"550/800"},{"Grade":"Ist"}]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modify your data from backend and add keys to data as below , it will easy to know where have to loop and don't need to know when to stop**

```
var data: {
  student: {
    "_id": {
      "$id": "5715f58299fbad800100003a"
    },
    "student_id": 36,
    "‌​registration_temp_pe‌​rm_no": "453654",
    "rol‌​l_no": "31",
    "admissio‌​n_date": "04/12/2016"‌​,
    "first_name": "Momin‌​",
    "middle_name": "Bas‌​hir",
    "last_name": "Ra‌​ther",
    "dob": "7/9/199‌​5",
    "gender": "Male",
    "‌​blood_group": "",
    "bir‌​th_place": "",
    "nation‌​ality": "",
    "language"‌​: "",
    "religion": "Isla‌​m"...
  },
  marks: {
    subjects: [
      {
        "Physic‌​s": "150.00/200",
        "Sta‌​tus": "Pass"
      },
      {
        "Scien‌​ce": "400.00/600",
        "St‌​atus": "Pass"
      }
    ],
    "Tot‌​al Marks": "550/800",
    "Grade": "Ist",

  }
}
```

Try loop using below code

```
//Without modify json from backend
var allSubjects=data[1][1]; 

//With modify json from backend
var allSubjects=data[1][1]['Sub‌​jects']; 

for(var i in allSubjects){


 var keysOfObject=Object.Keys(allSubjects[i]);

  $("#subjectsMarks li").html(keysOfObject[0] + ':' + allSubjects[i][keysOfObject[0]]+ "<br/>"allSubjects[i]["Status"]);
/* //console.log(allSubjects[i].keysOfObject[0], keysOfObject[0])
 console.log(allSubjects[i]);*/


}
```

**2nd version loop**

```
for(var i in allSubjects){

 var subject='';
 for(var key in allSubjects[i]){
  subject=key;
  break;
}
 //var keysOfObject=//Object.Keys(allSubjects[i]);

  $("#subjectsMarks li").html(subject + ':' + allSubjects[i][subject]]+ "<br/>"allSubjects[i]["Status"]);

console.log(allSubjects[i][subject], subject)

}
```

Comment: It is not possible to add data like this in backend because the above data is being fetched from several lines of code. Please help me!!!

Comment: There is duplication of subject and marks array , if there is single array i can provide u solution , how could we know that which array is of subject and marks array @Nida

Comment: I have modified backend code...{"profile_pic":""},"routeid":0,"routearray":[{"routeid":2,"academicyear":"2016","current":0,"vehicleno":"1233455","dateofassignment":"04/19/2016"},{"routeid":5,"academicyear":"2016","current":0,"vehicleno":"1","dateofassignment":"04/20/2016"}],"courseId":{"$id":"5706236b99fbadb82d000029"}},[{"Subjects":[{"Physics":"150.00/200","Status":"Pass"}]},{"Subjects":[{"Physics":"150.00/200","Status":"Pass"},{"Science":"400.00/600","Status":"Pass"}]},{

Comment: Now it looks like above

Comment: it is showing console.log(allSubjects); as undefined... help

Comment: After implementing data[1][1] directly it is adding subjects array to allSubjects bu it is throwing Uncaught TypeError: Object.Keys is not a function

Comment: Check my 2nd version of loop in my answer @Nida

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142886/discussion-between-love-kesh-and-nida).